# OSBTreeException: Key size is more than allowed, operation was canceled

Tags: orientdb, orientdb-2.1

I'm working with OrientDB 2.1.9, trying to bulk load data into a graph database. The database contains pages (vertices) and links between the pages (edges).

I have defined a vertex type for the page vertices. Since I'll want to search for pages by title, I also create an index on the title property.

```
graph.createVertexType("Page");
graph.createKeyIndex("title", Vertex.class, 
            new Parameter<String, String>("type", "UNIQUE"), 
            new Parameter<String, String>("class", "Page")
        );
```

I use a single call to add the vertex for the page and set its title property.

```
graph.addVertex("class:Page", "title", page);
```

While running the bulk import I encounter the following exception:

```
Caused by: com.orientechnologies.orient.core.index.sbtree.local.OSBTreeException: Key size is more than allowed, operation was canceled. Current key size 20016, allowed  10240
at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.index.sbtree.local.OSBTree.put(OSBTree.java:233)
```

I don't understand why the exception happens. The key value is e.g. "Drie (sport)", which is no where near 10Kb.

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: Hi, sure that is not near the 10kb, could you send me database with schema so I will reproduce issue ?

Comment: Hi, I have tried your code with graph.addVertex("class:Page", "title", "Drie"); and it works.
What contains the variable page ?

Comment: @AlessandroRota: It's titles from wikipedia articles that I extracted from wikimedia dumps.

Comment: @AndreyLomakin: you can find the JSON export on [filedropper](http://www.filedropper.com/wikipedia)

Comment: @Jiri I think that you can't insert a vertex with a title(String) that have more than 10240 bytes

Comment: @AlessandroRota That's how I interpret the exception message too. But the title is no where near that size.